# Declaring Variables in VBA to analyze Strings (But offset to see numbers!)

Tags: vba, excel

In the following code I have declared c to be used, but it seems as though it only works with numbers. I am looking for a string to compare with another string in another table on the same sheet.

The catch that makes this tricky is that I would like to offset the value to the cell adjacent to the left, and then compare one date with another. To make it more clear, my data is formatted like this: (Call it SetA)

```
         A        B         C         D    E  F      G          H          I
CreateTime  LotID  AnalysisSet  Slot#  X  Y  ResultType  TermName  ResultName
```

A few more columns to the right.... Lets call this SetB

```
     Y        Z        AA       AB    AC  AD     AE          AF        AG
CreateTime  LotID  AnalysisSet  Slot#  X  Y  ResultType  TermName  ResultName
```

Here is the code:

```
Sub AIM36DBOCompare()
Dim n As Integer
n = 2
Dim PasteCount As Integer
Dim test1 As Long
Dim test2 As Long

PasteCount = 41
    Range("AD2:AD1000").Copy Destination:=Range("S41" & Lastrow)
    Do While n <= 1000
        If Cells(26, n) <> 0 Then
'--------------------------------------------
            With Worksheets(1).Range("b2:b10000")
                Set c = .Find(Cells(n, 26).String, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not c Is Nothing Then
                    Do
                        test1 = Cells(n, 25).Value
                        test2 = c.Offset(0, -1)
                        If Abs(Cells(n, 25) - c.Offset(0, -1)) <= 100 Then
                            c.Offset(0, -1).Copy
                            Cells(PasteCount, 17).Select
                            Selection.Paste
                            PasteCount = PasteCount + 1
                            Exit Do
                        End If
                        Set c = .Find(Cells(n, 26).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
                    Loop While Not c Is Nothing
                End If
            End With
'--------------------------------------------
        End If
        If Cells(11, n) = 0 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    n = n + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

So to be more clear here is the code: Find LotID in SetB, find the first (of multiple) corresponding LotID in SetA. Compare date in SetB to the date in SetA by offsetting the variable by one cell and then subtracting the two (using absolute value).

If it is under 100 days, then do stuff!

Its not doing stuff :(. The date in SetA is showing up as nothing. I think it is because of the variable being used. Please help!

The code fails at Test2 (and consequently) in the "if test" `If Abs(Cells(n, 25) - c.Offset(-1, 0)) <= 100 Then`

[image]

Comment: Run through your code 1 line at a time to see where it fails. You need to attempt to debug before you can find anything out.

Comment: re: `Destination:=Range("S41" & Lastrow)` if *Lastrow* was 1000 are you trying to paste into S411000?

Comment: Grade ' Eh' Bacon: Added the failure location, Jeeped: It is pasting into the last empty cell starting from S41.

Comment: I think the failure has something to do with m,y "c" reference, but I am nost sure how to reference in a way that will allow me to work with the found cells and the rows that contain them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you want to take the cell to the left of c. In the code, you are getting the value from the cell above. To see this, try the code below:

```
Sub test()
    Dim add As String
    Dim c As Range
    Dim offsetRange As Range

    Set c = Range("B2")
    Set offsetRange = c.Offset(-1, 0)
    add = offsetRange.Address
    Debug.Print add
    Debug.Print offsetRange.Value
End Sub
```

Offset takes rows first, then columns, so you would want to swap to 0 and -1, as below:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim add As String
    Dim c As Range
    Dim offsetRange As Range

    Set c = Range("B2")
    Set offsetRange = c.Offset(0, -1)
    add = offsetRange.Address
    Debug.Print add
    Debug.Print offsetRange.Value
End Sub
```

Also, you are declaring and getting the values for the variables test1 and test2, but you are not using these values when doing the comparison.

Comment: Tes1 and Test2 are for debugging so that I can see what the values of them are when I step through the code.

Comment: So this does work with getting the correct address as far as I can tell, but the problem Is that I wish to use that address in a calculation as you can see below that. Abs(Cells(n, 25) - c.Offset(0, -1).Address)

Is there a way to reference the address outputted into an equation?

Comment: Using this "add" becomes "A$11$," now I want to use that though. Oh, and I flipped the offset ;) good catch, thank you.

Comment: Perfect. I am going to edit with the finished code, this works with just  a bit of extra stuff!

Comment: You can leave off the .Address - that was just to make it easy to see that which cell was being returned by the offset. If you just use c.Offset(0,-1) it will return a range, and you can use it as before.